# PHP and jQuery progress bar while parsing

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, progress-bar

I was wondering how I could go about making a progress bar for parsing HTML data. Essentially the user searches something and I parse another website. I tried doing it with getting the amount of objects found in an array then dividing 100 by it, and getting the current one in a for loop and multiplying it by 100/total. Then I would update a text file with the value. Then update the progress bar with that value. However, I want a more efficient way to do it. Also it has to be unique to each user. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found another way to do it, this is to help all of those people that have the same question. I found it out on here http://w3shaman.com/article/php-progress-bar-script

```
<?php
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Progress Bar</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Progress bar holder -->
<div id="progress" style="width:500px;border:1px solid #ccc;"></div>
<!-- Progress information -->
<div id="information" style="width"></div>
<?php
// Total processes
$total = 10;
// Loop through process
for($i=1; $i<=$total; $i++){
    // Calculate the percentation
    $percent = intval($i/$total * 100)."%";

    // Javascript for updating the progress bar and information
    echo '<script language="javascript">
    document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML="<div style=\"width:'.$percent.';background-color:#ddd;\">&nbsp;</div>";
    document.getElementById("information").innerHTML="'.$i.' row(s) processed.";
    </script>';


// This is for the buffer achieve the minimum size in order to flush data
    echo str_repeat(' ',1024*64);


// Send output to browser immediately
    flush();


// Sleep one second so we can see the delay
    sleep(1);
}
// Tell user that the process is completed
echo '<script language="javascript">document.getElementById("information").innerHTML="Process completed"</script>';
?>
</body>
</html>
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Executing length php process **while showing progress**, even having **multiple progress bars** on same page and **pre/post hooks**: http://pastebin.com/KSxjC01r

*I've done it for myself, because I need it.*

Feel free to use it.

Comment: Error 404 on the link

Answer (score 0):

If you use PHP for the parsing part then this means that you should somehow get information from that process. This also means that you have to (probably) make ajax requests to another php script which monitors the first one or at least gets some log information from it. I don't think that PHP is the right choice for that. I'll suggest to use nodejs. There, you are able to implement real time socket communication, which is kinda easy.

Comment: Well, the parsing process was built with PHP. Using the class simple_html_dom

Comment: In PHP you can't access already started script. During its execution you can only programatically leave markers in database or file. Then you can read them with another php script, but that sounds really bad idea. In general you have javascript API for getting infromation about uploading of files, but not for script execution.

Comment: So your saying that it is NOT a good idea to write to a file in the PHP while loop?

Comment: Yes. You should not rely on a file writing. Even if you use different files for the different users, which will make your site really heavy. Also will slow down the whole process.

Comment: Okay, what about writing to a cookie?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that you should reload the page to set the cookie value. In your case, you are running php script and you can't reload it till it parses the whole html.

Comment: So your saying the nodejs thing is the only option. I've never heard of nodejs, do I have to rewrite my whole parser?

Comment: Probably nodejs is not the only one option, but yes you should probably write your parse. However you may use jquery there and make your life easier. To work with jquery in the backend and parse the html will be much much faster and I guess that you don't even need a preloader. Just *working* and *done*. Using nodejs also means that your hosting provided should support that.

Answer (score -2):

I've used the solution user3393366 put forth in a post above, and though it outputs an ugly amount of javascript code, it worked real well.  I modified it to put out multicolor progress bars based on percentage complete, fixed the multi progress bars on a page issue, added titles to the progress bars, and made optional hide progress bars at completion functions..  so, no jquery or ajax needed, and works well.. be more than willing to post my mods here.. Sure, maybe not cutting edge stuff.. but gets the job done.