# PHP batch processing class with progress bar and handling timeout

Tags: php, apache, batch-processing

I am working with Soundcloud API to get the group members' information. Now there are thousands of members in a group. I need to get this done in a "Batch Process" and have to show a progress bar. How can I do this? Any technical solution, please?

**Edit:** The class should keep in mind about the "server load". I mean to say, server shouldn't be very busy to process this and the CPU load shouldn't get high.

Comment: How can you do what? Read soundcloud, or show a progress bar? For the latter, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18566362/php-and-jquery-progress-bar-while-parsing

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "Server load"?

Comment: @GolezTrol, I have edited my question. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

For the progress bar part, the question I mentioned in my comment doesn't seem to provide a proper answer. With some further googling and experimenting I came to this solution, which seems to work in both Chrome and IE11.

```
<?php 
  set_time_limit(0); // Don't timeout.
  header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' ); 
?><!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<progress id="progress" max="10" value="1">
</progress>
<div id="test">
Hello world
</div>

<?php
// Apparently this is needed to disable buffering.
ob_implicit_flush(true);
ob_end_flush();

$colors = array('red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'red', 'green', 'black', 'white', 'blue', 'green', 'pink');
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; ++$i)
{
  // Outputting a large chunk of data is also mentioned as a work-around, but for me it didn't work.
  // echo str_repeat(' ', 10000);

  // Instead of sleeping, this is where your actual processing would go.
  sleep(1);

  // Echo a small Javascript to update the status.
  ?>
    <script>
    document.getElementById('progress').value = <?=$i?>;
    document.getElementById('test').style.backgroundColor = '<?=$colors[$i]?>';
    document.getElementById('test').innerText = '<?=$i*10?>% done';
    </script>
  <?php
  // The script is flushed right away, and the browser should execute it right away.
  flush();
}
```